# How to start a child process successfully in node without waiting for it to complete?

Tags: node.js, child-process

How do I ensure the child process has started without waiting for it to complete?
Here is my code.

```
const runMyProc = () => {

const cmd = "MyProc";

const MyProcProc = spawn(cmd);

if(!MyProcProc)
    return false;

logger.info(`Started ${cmd} process with PID [${MyProcProc.pid}].`); 

MyProcProc.on('error', (err) => {
  logger.error(`Failed to run MyProc app ${err}`); 
});
MyProcProc.on('close', (code) => {
  logger.info(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`)

});
MyProcProc.on('exit', (code) => {
  logger.info(`Process exited with exit code  ${code}`); 
});

return true;
}
```

Comment: `runMyProc()` already starts the child process without waiting for it to complete.  I"m not sure what else you want it to do?

Comment: @jfriend00 I want confirmation that it started.

Comment: You could have it send you a message when it's running either over the child's stdout or if it's a nodejs process using the IPC channel with `process.send()`.  Other than that, I don't think there's any way to know.  It either runs and then completes at some point or it gives you an error and you get the error event.